# Coolant level fluctuation

Tags: nissan, coolant, diesel, x-trail

2011 Nissan Xtrail, 2L diesel, 160.000 km.

I noticed that while driving, coolant level drops below minimum mark. If i let the engine cool down, level rises to the same mark, almost to max.

What could.it be?

Thanks

Comment: What you are describing is the exact opposite of how this should work. Automotive cooling systems are pretty simple. When water/coolant heats up it expands. The opposite happens when it cools. Exorcist, perhaps?

Comment: @TimNevins I don't know... Thinking air bubbles in the system

Comment: Are there any problems with it overheating?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Well, I think that the coolant from the overflow tank was going in an electric turbo cooler pump wich runs after turning the engine off. But i do have a new question open on a possible overheat problem with this car, maybe related...: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/68630/possible-overheat

Comment: The reason if I asked if there was any overheating issues is, if there isn't any ... don't worry about it. It is probably running as designed.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Yeah, no coolant loss so far. Let's hope so.